# Issue building proper array from tableview selections

Tags: arrays, swift

Essentially I am adding or removing the cell values to an array that is built up based on which cells are selected/deselected.

**I need my array to look like this:**

```
[{"value":"One","id":"1"},{"value":"two","id":"4"}]
```

**Currently it looks like this:**

```
["One", "two"]
```

Currently the array does not include the struct titles (id and value) and does not include the curly brackets. The values for the id and values are coming from the array populating the tableview. How can this be done?

**My code so far:**

```
var structure = [Struct]()
var selectionArray: [String] = []

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell!.accessoryType = .checkmark
    let item = structure[indexPath.row]
    let cellvalue = item.value
    selectionArray.append(cellvalue)

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell!.accessoryType = .none
    let item = structure[indexPath.row]
    let cellvalue = item.value

    if let index = selectionArray.index(of: cellvalue) {
                selectionArray.remove(at: index)
            }

}

struct Struct: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let value: String
    
}
```

Comment: The result you want looks like JSON. Do you want to encode your array to a JSON string instead?

Comment: Yes, including both the id and value of the row selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store the `selectionArray` array as a property at all. You can use [`indexPathsForSelectedRows`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows) to get all the selected rows. So you can generate the array whenever you need it.

```
let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows ?? []
// this contains the selected structs
let selectedStructs = selectedIndexPaths.map { structure[$0.row] }
```

Now you can encode it to JSON:

```
// remember to conform Struct to Codable!
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
do {
    let jsonData = try encoder.encode(selectedStructs)
    // if you want to see the encoded JSON string:
    print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I seem to get the error Value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'selectedIndexPaths'

Comment: @JeffRenson Oops! I seem to have brainfarted. You should be able to tell that I meant `indexPathsForSelectedRows` from the first paragraph :)

Comment: Much appreciated